# Values aren't correctly being assigned to array, (basic)

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[]args) { 
    int[] array = new int[10];

    for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i; 
    }
    System.out.println(array);
}
}
```

Why is the output "[I@677327b6"? I am just trying to assign values to an array. I know this is a very basic question, however, I've been struggling to find the answer.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your input should work fine. If you want to print array elements, the statement should be like 

for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]); 
    }

Comment: "[I@677327b6" it is a string that desrcibes the identity of the array. If you want to see its content, you can write:  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));